# edit bst file so that the extra-label appears only on the second occurrence

Tags: bibtex

I am sure my question is a really easy one, but the syntax of the bst files is way too complicated for me.
I would like to edit my bst file so that, in case the same author has multiple publications in the same year, it would print:

Doe (1900)
Doe (1900a)
Doe (1900b)

instead of

Doe (1900a)
Doe (1900b)
Doe (1900c)

I have figured out that it all happens in this area:

```
STRINGS { longest.label last.label next.extra }

INTEGERS { longest.label.width last.extra.num number.label }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label} { "" 'longest.label :=  #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.label :=  "" 'next.extra :=  #0 'longest.label.width :=  #0 'last.extra.num :=  #0 'number.label := }

FUNCTION {forward.pass} { last.label label =    { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
     last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=    }    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
     "" 'extra.label :=
     label 'last.label :=    }  if$  number.label #1 + 'number.label := }

FUNCTION {reverse.pass} { next.extra "b" =    { "a" 'extra.label := }  'skip$  if$  extra.label 'next.extra :=  extra.label  duplicate$ empty$    'skip$    { "{\natexlab{" swap$ * "}}" * }  if$  'extra.label :=  label extra.label * 'label := }

EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}

ITERATE {forward.pass}

REVERSE {reverse.pass}
```

But this is the best I can do… Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong or bothersome with1990a, 1990b, and 1990c? Are you maybe publishing in a field where it's more common to write the year labels as 1990, 1990a, and 1990b?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is actually nothing "wrong" with it. I am only used to 1900, 1900a, 1900b (extra label being actually quite rarely used)…

Answer (score 2):

I figured something out. This isn't very graceful, but it did the trick. I made the counting start with "`" (acute, that is, the previous ASCII character in the table) instead of "a" in FUNCTION {forward.pass}, which now reads like this:

```
FUNCTION {forward.pass}
    { last.label label =
        { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
        last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=
            }
            { "`" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
            "" 'extra.label :=
            label 'last.label :=
        }
    if$
    number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
    }
```

I have some doubts about this being a stable solution, though…